# Charging NiMH cells which are welded together—safe?

Tags: circuit-design, charger, discharge, nimh

I am attempting to recondition sticks (groups of cells in series) of NiMH batteries from a Honda Accord Hybrid Battery.

The cells in question are nominally 1.2V cells with a capacity of 6500mAh. There are 12 to a set, resulting in a total of 14.4V. I believe the overall health of the sticks to be at least moderately damaged (though I am unsure which ones), so this is an attempt to bring the pack back from the dead rather than spend thousands on a new or refurbished pack. I have the option to replace individual sticks.

I purchased a Tenergy T180 universal charger and have a few problems with it.

First, and I hope this gets indexed by Google, the Tenergy T180 capacity cutoff setting ***does not work***. I saw this mentioned by a single Amazon review and thought perhaps he received a bad item, but I can confirm it to be true. This doesn't matter to most users of this charger because they are not charging a pack which can be expected to come close to the maximum voltage the charger provides, thus making it unable to detect the -DeltaV that stops the charging normally, which I presume does work. This resulted in putting almost 7000mAh into a stick and finding it rather warm. I'm glad I was checking every so often. I believe this can and may have damaged my cells further.

Second, the discharge power is only 20W. For my sticks, that means it can only drain 1A and the whole process takes over 6 hours. I cannot find a much better option for less than 150$.

I am open to suggestions though. The only thing I've found so far is the Ultra Power UP6+.

To offset the second problem, I thought of splitting the stick in half, to increase the discharge amperage and be able to faster see if a cell is unrecoverable. The "stick" is actually 2 groups of 6 cells (7.2v each). The cells are strongly welded together and covered so I do not want to split them up there. The groups are then tack-welded together with a metal bar at one end to reduce the length.

I am curious if inserting the charging wires around one group of the stick's cells will cause damage to the other group, i.e.:

```
Charger + >>---[ Group 1 ]------[ Group 2 ]---<< Charger -
```

becomes

```
[ Group 1 ]---|---[ Group 2 ]--|
              |                |
 Charger + >>-|                |-<< Charger -
```

such that group 1 is part of an incomplete circuit, but touches group 2, which is in a loop with the charger.

This would let me charge and discharge faster and give me a more granular view of what's going on in each stick. But obviously I do not wish to damage the other group of cells.

The aim here is to make spotting the -DeltaV easier so I avoid accidentally overcharging the pack, as well as reduce the time it takes to discharge to speed up eliminating good and bad cell groups.

Comment: How do you plan to balance the cells?

Comment: I will choose the sticks which are most similar in terms of capacity and voltage loss under load and group them in parallel, then trickle charge the whole set at a very low current, based on information I've found elsewhere.

Comment: There may be cells, that show acceptable capacity but have large leakage current. After a week they may be empty to your surprise.

Comment: That's true. Do you think a week is long enough to be sure they self-discharge evenly?

Comment: @FawltyPlay why are you assuming that all cells in a string will self-discharge at the same rate?

Comment: @SolarMike I am not, but I can't do any better because of the welding. If the packs were separable I would be charging individual (or small clumps of) cells. The manufacturing done by Honda makes it too difficult to take anything apart. Many have had success in the past without taking the sticks apart but it's all inexact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connecting as in your second diagram can't really damage the group 1 cells as one end of that group isn't connected to anything.

You're going to need a strategy to replace any dead cells that won't hold a charge. If the pack as a whole isn't working, then there are probably a few dead cells in there.

Comment: Misread your post, probably because I was barely awake. Thanks.